# Adding Yandex Satellite map in OpeLayers

Tags: openlayers, satellite, yandex

How can I add Yandex satellite map in OpenLayers?

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: "Yandex Uydu",
  baseLayer: true,
  visible: true,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'http://vec0{1-4}.maps.yandex.net/tiles?lang=tr_TR&l=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',
    maxZoom: 19,
    attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
    html: '© Yandex'
    })],
     projection: 'EPSG:3395',
     tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
       extent: [-20037508.342789244, -20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244, 20037508.342789244]
     })
   })
})
```

[image: My code]

Comment: `https://sat0{1-4}.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=sat&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`

Comment: Can we put this comment in answer form if it solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  satellite image tile url template is

```
https://sat0{1-4}.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=sat&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

A language parameter is accepted but since there are no labels it has no effect